# When does an SR weapon outmatch an SSR weapon?

Tags: tower-of-fantasy

Weapons are graded with SSR being the top, SR mid-tier and R lowest tier.

Wishes are obviously more likely to produce SR grade weapons (guaranteed 1 on 10 pulls), and as such they will gain more passive stars.

Comparing an SSR 0* weapon to an SR 6* weapon makes for a difficult choice. For example,

*Edited image to compare DPS vs DPS*
[image: Dual EM Stars vs Thunderous Halberd]

Numerically, it seems that the Halberd is the one to go for, but if that's the case wouldn't that make the SSR weapons not worth picking up until they have enough Passive Stars to eclipse the SR weapons?

How many stars does an SSR weapon need before it becomes more viable than SR 6*? Or does this relate strictly to the CS value given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On paper the basic stats lean towards the star'd up SR weapons, but the "meta" part comes in how the weapon actually plays and is used. Right now you are comparing a defense weapon vs a DPS weapon so some things may not apply/compare 1:1. That said, Rosy Edge and Thunderous Halberd are both generally used as shield breakers.

Thunderous halberd basic attack combo is a lot of quick pokes, its special skill is an uppercut launcher, and 'hold' combo attack is another launcher. While this is useful on most regular enemies, bosses cant really be launched. This cuts the halberds usefulness immensely, but it still does a pretty good job at rushing down shields.

Rosy Edge on the other hand, has slow sweeping hits with a good amount of AOE, The special skill is an uninterruptable ranged series of power hits, the hold combo is another launcher, but there is additional special attack that is a powerful spin2win as long as your have endurance. These factors are what give the Rosy Edge advantage. It can can provide more sustained heavy damage for breaking down shields.

CS really only takes the weapon stats and matrix stats into account. How the weapon is actually used on the field determines its effectiveness/tier, and Rosy just does everything better than Halberd. That said, Halberd is still a very competent shield breaker if Gacha is being cruel.

To answer your main question of

> How many stars does an SSR weapon need before it becomes more viable than SR 6*?

An SSR at star 0 is the same if not better than an SR at star 6. Especially if the role is the same. It's CS will be lower, but the weapon's "innate" features and abilities is what matters the most, not stats. Scythe of the Crow would probably be the SSR version of the Halberd (DPS ShieldBreaker), and one combo in its default state is clear as day more potent than the Halberd.

Now, this doesn't mean SRs are bad. Really any weapon at any star level can be viable (unless you are doing like competitive pvp or world bosses and such)

Comment: "How many stars does an SSR weapon need before it becomes more viable than SR 6*?" - "Yes"

Comment: I can update the question once I have an SSR dps weapon

Comment: I think the point that @Rapitor is making is that many of the SSR weapons are more functional in battle due to their traits, such as more stagger, or such.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica I updated the answer to clear that up, but the answer is immediately.

Comment: you should add that in the ranked PvP system (Apex League), any weapon and relic you own is balanced to have max stars in there, so by that logic, SSR outstats SR weapons (matrices are ignored in Apex League)